# How to access windows from MAC machine?

Tags: windows, osx, virtual-machine

I am using MACbook pro with processor 2.5GHz
I need to use a software that is supported by only Windows OS at the moment.

What are my options please? I cant afford to buy windows machine now.
As an alternate someone suggested me to use VMware. Can anyone share me if you know steps of doing it please?

Or any other suggestions are more helpful

Comment: What about installing [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) on MacOSX? It's 100% free, unlike a virtual machine that you still have to pay a Windows license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would go with Oracle VM [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) rather than VMWare *(as VirtualBox is Free).*

In either case you need to buy, *or possibly download*, a Windows install disk *or .iso image,* that is suitable for the software that you need to run. N.B. if your machine is 32 bit you **must** use 32 bit Windows & programs, *likewise if the software you need to run is only available 64 bit you will need a 64 bit Windows install.* If your processor is 64 bit then you can use either 32 or 64 bit installs.

Both VMWare and VirtualBox hold your hand when creating a virtual machine, simply select New Virtual Machine and follow the prompts as you can see below for VirtualBox (on Windows).

[image]